# External Bisectors of Triangle ABC

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

[image]

The **exterior angle bisectors** of $\angle B$ and $\angle C$  intersect  on point $O$.
$\angle BOC=70°$.

**Find** $\angle OAC$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that exterior angle of $\angle b$ = $2\beta$ =  $\angle A + 180 - \angle c$
Suppose exterior angle of $\angle c$ is $2\alpha$, so
$$2\beta = A + 180 - 2\alpha$$, but $\alpha + \beta =  180 - 70 = 110$,so
$$A = 220 - 180 = 40$$
That's was part one, now part two.
Let's prove that AO is bisector.
Let's take the heights on BC , (AB) and (AC), where (AB) mean line AB.
So as BO and CO are bisectors, then it's easy to prove that O  - is center of some circle , which intersect BC, (AC), (AB) , so O  is lying on AO - bisector, so $\angle OAC = 20$

Comment: We are talking about $\angle OAC$

Comment: @EitanPorat sorry, my bad

Comment: Or it's better to write $altitude$?